# camel jpa component + maxMessagesPerPoll not working

Tags: jpa, apache-camel

My understanding about "maxMessagesPerPoll" in camel-jpa component is that when i set "maxMessagesPerPoll=4", 4 records will be fetched for each poll.BUT NOT THE SAME 4 RECORDS  FOR EACH POLL.I SHOULD GET NEXT 4 SET OF RECORDS.

But when i set the parameter as 4, iam always getting the same first 4 records all the time.
how do i get the next subsequent set records for each poll.

Idea behind this - I want to process the reords in batches and not all the data at the same time.

Just want to have scrollable - KIND OF.

how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the rows you have previously process as processed, either by deleting them, or update some column to indicate processed, so the next poll do not pick them up.

Comment: I will schedule a replay mechanism which will pick all the messages from the table and send for processing.
When i update the flag to 'Y' and when the second trigger happens there would be record to reprocessing in this case/

Comment: This is the scenario. I will have to pick all the messages from table for say 3 times a day and send it for processing.

Answer (score 1):

Have a flag in a row and set it true after consumption and put that condition in your JPA query.

```
eg:- from MyEntity where flag = false;
```

camel will do this for you.
you just need to add a method in Your Entity.

```
    @Consumed
    public void updateRecord() {
        setFlag(true);
    }
```

next time all the new rows will be fetched.